# Delete rows if cell contains certain text

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete the entire rows for cell that contain 'Total' and 'Nett' in column C.

I have tried the macro recording using Auto Filter but it only delete rows up to a specified range (which may differ if I use other set of data).

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you please post the code that you recorded with the macro recorder?

Comment: Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$5000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Total"
    
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$5000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Nett"
    
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
  
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Just copy and paste this sub into your file. To use it, select the SINGLE column that you want to evaluate. This will go through every cell that has been selected, and if it matches the criteria, it will delete the entire row. Let me know if you have any questions. Good luck!

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    'Enter the text you want to use for your criteria
    Const DELETE_CRITERIA = "Test"
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim numRows As Long, Counter As Long, r As Long

    'Make sure that we've only selected a single column
    If Selection.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox ("This only works for a single row or a single column. Try again.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    numRows = Selection.Rows.Count - 1

    ReDim arrCells(0 To 1, 0 To numRows) As Variant

    'Store data in array for ease of knowing what to delete
    Counter = 0
    For Each myCell In Selection
      arrCells(0, Counter) = myCell
      arrCells(1, Counter) = myCell.Row
      Counter = Counter + 1
    Next myCell

    'Loop backwards through array and delete row as you go
    For r = numRows To 0 Step -1
        If InStr(1, UCase(arrCells(0, r)), UCase(DELETE_CRITERIA)) > 0 Then
            Rows(arrCells(1, r)).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I am really new to VBA. 
1) Can you explain what ' means when you include it in the code?
2) Where should I type in the search rule - ie; Total & Nett
3) How can I enter the code in the grey box like you did

Comment: No problem - we've all been there. The `'` means it's a comment. The program will ignore that line. I included the comments so you could see what is happening at each step.

Comment: Thanks for the info. How abt Question 2 & 3 in my comment?

Comment: Sorry about that - I'm answering from my phone now. For #2) you change the criteria where it says `DELETE_CRITERIA = "Test"` - change Test to be whatever phrase you're looking for. For #3, you can either use an appropriate number of spaces or click the button that says code block in the editor.

Comment: I just realized this script looks for cells that are EXACTLY the criteria you're looking for - not just CONTAINING the text. I will update tomorrow morning.

Comment: No worries. #4) How to select the single column for filter (column C), #5) Where and how should the array looks like?

Comment: I fixed it now. It will look for contains but is not case sensitive. To select the column, you literally select it in the workbook with your cursor. You don't need to worry about an array - the vba builds it automatically.

Comment: So, I highlight the column before I run the macro? When I keyed in additional criteria (ie; Const DELETE_CRITERIA = "Total", "Nett" - it shows 'Compile error. Expected: identified'

Comment: You can't have multiple criteria. Run it for one word and then the next.

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through cells in Column C and delete the entire row if the cell contains either "Total" or "Nett". Keep in mind that it is case sensitive, so the first letter of "Nett" or "Total" would need to be capitalized for this to find it. There can be other text in the cell however. Also note that the references are not fully qualified (ie Workbook().Worksheet().Range()) because you did not provide a workbook or worksheet name. Let me know if this does not work for you.

```
Sub Delete()

Dim i as Integer

For i = Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
   If Instr(1, Cells(i, 3), "Total") <> 0 Or Instr(1, Cells(i,3),"Nett") <> 0 Then
      Cells(i,3).EntireRow.Delete
   End If
Next i

End Sub
```